# Write rows in XML using XmlWriter

Tags: vb.net, row, xmlwriter

I'm tring to write rows with multiple values using XmlWriter (vb - VS2013 .net 4.0).
All I found googling, was examples of codes like this one:

```
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True

    Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("123.xml", settings)

    With XmlWrt
        .WriteStartDocument()
        .WriteComment("blablabla")
        .WriteStartElement("test1")
        .WriteStartElement("test2")
        .WriteString("text")
        .WriteEndElement()
        .WriteEndElement()
        .Close()
    End With
```

This is the output for the code above:

```
    <!-- blablabla -->
    <test1>
        <test2>text</test2>
    </test1>
```

But what a want is a line, that is a row with multiple values like this:

```
    <row Nome="value" Acessorio="value" CodigoNcm="99999999" EspecificacaoComplementar="value" Origem="value" Quantidade="0.01" UnidadeMedida="value" PesoUnitario="0.01" NomeFabricante="value" NumeroDocumentoNFouDI="0" CodigoTipoDocumento="2" OrigemItensFinanciaveis="value" CustoFOBUnitario="0.01" CustoCIFUnitarioDOLAR="0.01" ImpostoImportacaoUnitario="0.01" PisUnitario="0.01" CofinsUnitario="0.01" PaisOrigem="value" DireitosAntiDumpingUnitario="0.01" Seq-Componente="CMP-2" PaginaDI="1234"/>
```

I didn't find any method to write rows. How to i accomplish that?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: In XML, those key/value pairs on an element are called attributes.

Comment: Thaaaaanks Steven. That was i looking for!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone have the same question. This is the way:

```
    With XmlWrt
        .WriteStartElement("test1")
        .WriteAttributeString("key", "value")
        .WriteAttributeString("key", "value")
        .WriteEndElement()
        .Close()
    End With
```